# Flex HTML CSS Issues with linebreaks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following css attributes below, it works here, but i am not able to get it to work on the production environment. Its forcing me to add 'flex: 0 0 100%'. For now my solution is to set *{flex: 0 0 100%}, my assumption is that it has to do with flex-basis. Does someone have a better solution?

Screenshot rendering w/out my global solution

[image]

Screenshot rendering with my global solution
[image]

```css
<style>
.flex-container, .flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#my-account .warning-message {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px red; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; 
  box-shadow:0 0 10px red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="flex-row warning-message">
  <h2>No warnings!</h2>
  <p>This section will only load when a warning is picked up on the account, in the production environment</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I found out the problem, and edited my question. looking to confirm my flex-basis suspicion and for a better solution.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot showing what the problem is, visually?

Comment: I have a hunch you're meaning to add `flex-direction: column;` to `flex-row`, which would remove the need for all that `100%` nonsense.

Comment: @AndyHoffman added the screnshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the direction of your flexbox content. The default is `row`, but you should be using `column`. Notice how I've removed the `100%` values and content is still stacking properly.

```css
.flex-container,
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#my-account .warning-message {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

/* Ignore */
.flex-row h2,
.flex-row p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-account">
  <div class="flex-row warning-message">
    <h2>No warnings!</h2>
    <p>This section will only load when a warning is picked up on the account, in the production environment</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned, if what you're trying to achieve is getting "This section will only..." part to the next line instead of on the same line, the problem is in flexbox's default property of `flex-direction`.

When you gave `display: flex;` to `.flex-row`, it automatically defaults to `flex-direction: row;` which will make objects stack next to each other horizontally instead of vertically.

All you have to do is override the default by adding `flex-direction: column;` to `.flex-row` (and remove the `flex: 0 0 100%; flex-wrap: wrap;`).

Comment: Thanks for the info, helped clarify it along with Andy's help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution to get your layout is to don't add any CSS.

The reason you have a simple layout, which the element you used `h2` and `p` give you by default as they have `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

```css
p,
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.flex-row {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row warning-message">
  <h2>No warnings!</h2>
  <p>This section will only load when a warning is picked up on the account, in the production environment</p>
</div>
```